# Best way to separate two base64 strings

Tags: c#, base64

I am using standard input and output to pass 2 base64 strings from one application to another. What would be the best way separating them so I could get them as a two separate strings in other application? I was thinking using a simple comma, to separate them and then just use

`string[] s = output.Split(',');`

Where output is the data I read in from standard output.

Example with the comma:

> MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCv5E5Y0Wrad5FrLjeUsA71Gipl3mhjIuCw1xhj
>   jDwXN87lIhpE32UvItf+mvp8flQ+fhi5H0PditDCzUFg8lXuiuOXxelLWEXA8hs7jc+4zzR5ps3R
>   fOv3M6H8K5XGkwWLhVNQX47sAGyY/43JdbfX7+FsYUFeHW/wa2yKSMZS3wIDAQAB
>   ,HNJpFQyeyJoVbeEgkw/WNtzR0JTPIa1hlK1C8LbFcVcJfL33ssq3gbzi0zxn0n2WxBYKJZj2Kqbs
>   lVrmFbQJRgvq4ZNF4F8z+xjL9RVVE/rk5x243c3Szh05Phzx+IUyXJe6GkITDmsxcwovvzSaGhzU
>   3qQkNbhIN0fVyynpg0Kfm0WytuW71ku1eq45ibcczgwQLRJX1GKzC9wH7x/V36i6SpyrxZ/+uCIL
>   4QgnKt6x4QG7Gfk3Msam6h6JTFdzkeHJjq6JzeapdQn5LxeMY0jLGc4cadMCvy/Jdrcg02pG2wOO
>   /gJT77xvX+d1igi+BQ/YpFlwXI0BIuRwMAeLojmZdRYjJ+LY69auxgpnQvSF4A+Wc6Jo8m1pzzHB
>   yQvA8KyiRwbyijoBOsg+oK18UPFWeJ5hE3e+8l/WSEcii+oPgXyXTnK+seesGdOPeem3HukNyIps
>   L/StHZEkzeJFTr8LIB9HLqDikYU2mQjTiK5cIExoyy2Go+0ndL84rCzMZAlfFlffocL9x+SGyeer
>   M1mxmyDtmiQfDphEZixHOylciKUhWR00dhxkVRQ4Q9LYCeyGfDiewL+rm5se/ePCklWtTGycV9HM
>   H5vYLhgIkf5W6+XcqcJlE6vp4WWxmKHQYqRAdfW5MYWskx7jBDTMV2MLy7N6gQRQa/OpK8ruAbVf
>   MwWP1sGyhAxgrw/UxTH1tW498WI5JtQR3oub3+Uj5AqydhwzQtWM58WfVQXdv2bFZmGH7d9A+C95
>   DQ8QXKrV7Ot/wVq5KKLgpJy8iMe/G/iyXOmQhkLnZ3qvBaIJd+E2ZIVPty6XGMwgC4JebArr+a6V
>   Cb/SO+vR+eZmXLln/w==

Answer (score 50, accepted):

All you have to do is to use a separator which is not a valid Base64 character. **Comma** is not a base64 character so you can use.

Base64 characters are `[0-9a-zA-Z/=+]` (all numbers, uppercase, lowercase, forward slash plus and equal sign).

Comment: Don't forget `+` and `/` which are part of the base64 characters.

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a good solution. The comma cannot be part of a [base64 index table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) so it is a safe separator.

Answer (score -3):

You can wrap it i some XML.  the CDATA element is perfect for that.

Comment: I think it's going to be a bit overkill, but thanks for the suggestion!