# How to convert multiple images to csv?

Tags: csv, neural-network

I want to run some images through a neural network, and I want to create a .csv file for the data. How can I create a csv that will represent the images and keep each image separate?

Comment: Isn't a neural network a kind of model? How are you running images through a model, do you have some examples? Also examples of what you expect what the column headings and first few rows of the csv should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach is to use numpy to convert image to array, which   can then be  converted to a CSV file or simply a comma  separated list.

The csv data can be manipulated or original image can be retrieved when needed.

Here is a basic code that demonstrates above concept.

```
import Image
import numpy as np

#Function to convert image to array or list
def loadImage (inFileName, outType ) :
    img = Image.open( inFileName )
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )
    if outType == "anArray":
        return data
    if outType == "aList":
        return list(data)


#Load image to array
myArray1 = loadImage("bug.png", "anArray")

#Load image to a list
myList1 = loadImage("bug.png", "aList")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your image in [Base64](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) and still use CSV, since commas are not part of characters in Base64.

See: [Best way to separate two base64 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350590/best-way-to-separate-two-base64-strings)

Comment: Since the net would have to decode the input CSV either way, the format is irrelevant. Base64 just saves space over a vector/matrix of pixel values. That said, you are right that there are better options than CSV, some of which would have faster deserialization and better tooling.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. I assumed OP already has some reason to use CSV (e.g. a preexisting NN tool that reads CSV for input), where reading raw base64-encoded string would be nonsensical training example (unless you're training a network to decode base64 :p ).

Comment: It was definitely an underspecified question, and he absolutely might have. :)

1D Base64 string with no definition of # cols would be poor.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, create a storage location just for images.  If your images have unique filenames, then all you need to track is the filename.  If they do not have a unique filename, you can assign one using a timestamp+randomizer function to name the photo.  Once named, it must be stored in the proper location so that all you need is the filename in order to reference the appropriate image.
Due to size constraints, I would not recommend storing the actual images in the csv.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that depends a lot on what algorithm and what implementation you select. It is not even clear that CSV is the correct choice.

For your stated requirements, [Netpbm format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) comes to mind; if you want to have one line per image, just squish all the numbers into one line. Note that the naive neural network will ignore the topology of the image, you'd need a bit advanced setup to include it.